# Can't load Powershell profile using Ruby 2.3 on Windows

Tags: command-line, powershell, ruby

After upgrading from Ruby 2.2 to Ruby 2.3 powershell calls stopped working because powershell profiles are not loaded.

1) If I open a command prompt, it works:

```
C:\Users\administrador>powershell.exe ls


    Directory: C:\Users\administrador


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        26/06/2015     16:20            .android
d----        24/08/2015     16:25            .gem
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Contacts
d-r--        06/07/2017     16:53            Desktop
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Documents
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Downloads
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Favorites
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Links
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Music
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Pictures
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Saved Games
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Searches
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Videos
-a---        22/01/2015     11:18       1796 volshext.log
```

2) But if use Ruby, it doesn't work. I am executing command prompt as administrator:

```
irb(main):002:0> system("powershell ls")
File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

File C:\Users\administrador\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\Users\administrador\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException



    Directory: C:\Users\administrador


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        26/06/2015     16:20            .android
d----        24/08/2015     16:25            .gem
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Contacts
d-r--        06/07/2017     16:53            Desktop
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Documents
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Downloads
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Favorites
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Links
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Music
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Pictures
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Saved Games
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Searches
d-r--        30/06/2017     11:27            Videos
-a---        22/01/2015     11:18       1796 volshext.log


=> true
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the execution policy was set for the whole machine using `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in a normal PowerShell prompt. On a 64-bit system, there are actually two versions of PowerShell: one 64-bit and one 32-bit. In this situation, running PowerShell normally will get you the 64-bit version. It appears, though, that Ruby is a 32-bit process. Judging by the presence of `SysWOW64` in the error message, 32-bit Ruby is launching 32-bit PowerShell, which doesn't get the same view of the system as 64-bit PowerShell. Ruby-launched PowerShell doesn't see the altered execution policy, so it refuses to run the profile script.

To correct the problem, run the policy-setting command from an elevated 32-bit PowerShell prompt. You can get one of those from the "Windows PowerShell (x86)" entry in Start. You could also set the policy for just your user account:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

That appears to work across bitnesses. Finally, if you don't need the profile scripts to run, you also have the option of disabling profile loading with the `-noprofile` switch to `powershell`.